# How to update entire column in a single statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Ordinary HR scheme, how to update an entire column with a single request?

I am getting this error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
update depts 
set    tot_dept_sal =
       ( select sum(e.salary)
         from   depts d, employees e 
         where  e.department_id = d.department_id
         group by d.department_name );
```

There is a table DEPTS:

```
department_id department_name  Tot_dept_sal
------------- ---------------- ------------
10            Administration   null
20            Marketing        null
30            Purchasing       null
40            Human Resources  null
...
270           Payroll          null
```

and EMPLOYEES:

```
employee_id   last_name  salary departments_id
------------- ---------- ------ --------------
100           King       24000  90  
101           Kochhar    17000  90  
102           De Haan    17000  90  
103           Hunold     9000   60  
104           Ernst      6000   60
```

Comment: You'll need to share some sample data from these tables and what you are trying to update. Your query doesn't make much sense as-is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit]() your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed! (D they really teach that ancient, comma separated implicit joins in 2020?!? Scary...)

Comment: Are `depts` and `departments` supposed to be the same table? If so why is the table being updated referenced a second time in the subquery? And either way, how are you expecting the target table and the subquery to be correlated? It would also generally be useful to say what happens with your code - presumably you get a ORA-01427 error?

Answer (score 1):

You have already got the `departments` table in the outer `UPDATE` and you can just correlate the sub-query to the outer query rather than joining to it a second time within the sub-query:

```sql
update departments d
set tot_dept_sal = (
  select sum(e.salary)
  from   employees e 
  where  d.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID
  group by d.department_id
);
```

So, for your sample data (updated to have `depatment_id` values for the `employees` that match the `departments` table):

```sql
CREATE TABLE departments ( department_id, department_name, Tot_dept_sal ) AS
SELECT  10, 'Administration',  CAST( null AS NUMBER(8,0) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  20, 'Marketing',       CAST( null AS NUMBER(8,0) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  30, 'Purchasing',      CAST( null AS NUMBER(8,0) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  40, 'Human Resources', CAST( null AS NUMBER(8,0) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 270, 'Payroll',         CAST( null AS NUMBER(8,0) ) FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employees ( employee_id, last_name, salary, department_id ) AS
SELECT 100, 'King',    24000,  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 101, 'Kochhar', 17000,  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 102, 'De Haan', 17000,  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 'Hunold',   9000,  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 104, 'Ernst',    6000, 270 FROM DUAL;
```

Then after running the `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPARTMENT_NAME | TOT_DEPT_SAL
> ------------: | :-------------- | -----------:
>            10 | Administration  |        41000
>            20 | Marketing       |        26000
>            30 | Purchasing      |         null
>            40 | Human Resources |         null
>           270 | Payroll         |         6000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b02ac7f916daf34ce9bfeb04e1ac34b)*

Comment: You don't even need the `group by` clause here - can't decide if it adds clarity though *8-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MERGE statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO departments TRG
USING (SELECT department_id, SUM(salary) AS SALARY
         FROM employees
     GROUP BY department_id) SRC
ON (TRG.department_id = SRC.department_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TRG.Tot_dept_sal = SRC.SALARY;
```